# Memory allocation for a matrix

Tags: c, dynamic, malloc

I have written code that generates a matrix with **NODES** rows and each row has a user specified number of columns (see **node_degree** below). I then fill each entry in the matrix with some value (the value doesn't matter).

When I build the program on Fedora using Geany, I receive no error messages. However, when I run the program I get:

> ./geany run script.sh line 5: 3586 Segmentation fault (core
>   dumped)"./ ad_matrix_outside_main

Note: ad_matrix_outside_main is the name of the c file.

Here is the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define NODES (10)
#define CONNECTED (5)

int main()
{
int i, j;
double **matrix;

matrix = (double **)malloc(sizeof(double *)*NODES); 

int node_degree[CONNECTED]; //Example: 5 nodes are connected (have non-zero degree).    

for(i=0; i<CONNECTED; i++)
{
    printf("Enter degree of node %d\n", i);  //Index is node, value is degree. 
    scanf("%d", &node_degree[i]);                               
} 

for(i=0; i<CONNECTED; i++)
{
    matrix[i] = (double*)malloc( sizeof(double)* (node_degree[i] + 1) );
}

for(i=0; i<NODES; i++) 
{

    for(j=0; j<node_degree[i]; j++) 
    {
        matrix[i][j] = j; //j can be the node that node i connected to. 
    }
    matrix[i][j] = NODES; 
}

for(i=0; i<NODES; i++)
{
    free( matrix[i] );
}

free(matrix);
return(0);
}
```

What could be causing the error? I have a feeling my notation might be the problem.

Comment: Whenever you get a Segmentation fault, you should compile your code with `-g` gcc option and then enable the core dump using bash command `ulimit -c unlimited` and execute your binary so that you would get a core-dump. Then you can use gdb and `backtrace` to know the actual reason for crash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define NODES (10)
#define CONNECTED (5)

int main()
{
int i, j;
double **matrix;

matrix = (double **)malloc(sizeof(double *)*NODES); 

int node_degree[CONNECTED]; //Example: 5 nodes are connected (have non-zero degree).    

for(i=0; i<CONNECTED; i++)
{
    printf("Enter degree of node %d\n", i);  //Index is node, value is degree. 
    scanf("%d", &node_degree[i]);                               
} 

for(i=0; i<CONNECTED; i++)
{
    matrix[i] = (double*)malloc( sizeof(double)* (node_degree[i] + 1) );
```

//here you malloc for 5
    }

```
for(i=0; i<NODES; i++) 
{

    for(j=0; j<node_degree[i]; j++) 
    {
        matrix[i][j] = j; //j can be the node that node i connected to. 
    }
    matrix[i][j] = NODES;
```

//here you assign for 10!
    }

```
for(i=0; i<NODES; i++)
{
    free( matrix[i] );
}

free(matrix);
return(0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I should have spotted that.